# Can I connect a pen drive to my Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini using USB OTG?

Tags: usb-on-the-go, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I am using Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini. Can I connect my phone with a pen drive using an on-the-go (OTG) USB cable?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume, YES.

Currently, my Samsung Galaxy S4 (using the latest stock ROM) supports USB OTG.

Before that, I had a Samsung Galaxy S2. Using the stock ROM, I could not use USB OTG. So, I installed [USB OTG Helper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.shajul.usbotg), which requires your phone to have root. When I changed to CyanogenMod (CM) ROM 10.1, I did not need USB OTG Helper; it had USB OTG support.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe.  [Chainfire's USB host diagnostics reports](http://usbhost.chainfire.eu/?search=i8190) shows some instances of the Galaxy S3 Mini (model GT-i8190) as working with USB OTG on the stock ROM, but also about as many reports of it not working.  It looks like just about all instances of the successful OTG tests are on rooted devices.

About the only way you'll find out for sure is to try it for yourself.  Worst case, you're out the couple dollars the cable cost you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [Samsung Galaxy S III mini use USB-OTG with Total Commander](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JevEyriLXZ0) video on YouTube.

There video author shows how to enable USB-OTG in Samsung Galaxy S III mini using USB-OTG cable with power support (micro-USB male, micro-USB female for power or USB male for power, USB female) -- supposedly all you need is *reboot the phone while providing power via USB-OTG cable*.

The same solution is described in [[HOW-TO][TRICK]USB OTG ON S3Mini](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2186034) post on XDA-Developers forum -- this recommends USB OTG cable (which you need anyway to connect pendrive) and USB male to USB male cable to connect power via USB OTG.

Phone will show charging indicator (but actually not charging) while USB OTG is active.

---

Advantages of this method:

- Doesn't need root
- No need to install additional apps like [USB OTG Helper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.shajul.usbotg) (Samsung Galaxy S3 mini (GT-i1890) is on the [list of USB OTG MSC confirmed devices](https://usbotghelper.wordpress.com/confirmed-devices/)), or switching to [CyanogenMod](http://novafusion.pl/downloads/) ROM.

Disadvantages of this method:

- Needs reboot, extra hardware and access to charging to turn on
- Phone cannot be charged while USB OTG is active ('till reboot)
- Battery drain
- Restarting / rebooting turn it off

---

Not tested myself, as I don't have any such cable myself at this time.

Answer (score -1):

Since [this product](http://www.mobilefun.co.uk/mobile-fun-connection-kit-for-samsung-galaxy-s4-s3-note-2-p35462.htm) exists, I assume that you can connect memory devices (such as a thumbdrive/pendrive) to your phone with just a USB connection, the OTG cable that you mention is just an adapter for two different kinds of connectors of what is essentially the same type of connection (USB).

YMMV, but it should technically be possible to connect memory devices to your phone this way. Which ones work and which ones don't probably depends on many factors, such as the ROM running on your phone, the thumbdrive/SD card reader used and so on.

Comment: Note that the S3 and S3 mini are entirely different devices.  It uses an entirely different SoC than any version of the regular S3.