# How to access a memory stick using a OTG cable?

Tags: files, usb-on-the-go, usb-storage

I have a OTG cable connected to my phone and a memory stick on the other end. My android phone is rooted and I have no idea how to find/access the files on my memory stick. How do I access files from my memory stick with my phone?

EDIT: Is it also possible to watch videos from the memory stick without moving it to the phone's storage?

Answer (score 2):

You can access a memory stick via OTG cable if your phone supports it. See [Compro1's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/49571/5342) to check if your phone supports OTG; you may need to specify the correct code / model in the [USB Host Diagnostics](http://usbhost.chainfire.eu/) site.

In case your phone supports OTG but does not support it directly, [check out my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/49545/5342) which involves using USB OTG Helper.

As to your last question, YES. You can watch videos from the memory stick.